# What Utility Slicing decoration gives the biggest/most valuable lockboxes?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

There are Decorations (Utility) that you can get that give gathering skill items when you use them. I have a small Slicing one that gives me small lockboxes, but I was wondering if there was one that gives lock boxes with more credits in them. And, if so, which one should I get for the biggest lock boxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be the [Encrypted Terminal](http://tor-decorating.com/encrypted-terminal/), which gives the equivalent of Makeb's slicing nodes' lockboxes (level 51-55 or Grade 9).  Grade 11 nodes (Rishi/Yavin) have not been added as decorations yet.

Do note that this is an absolutely terrible way to farm credits ... a half hour spent slicing on Yavin will net you more than exhausting the decoration node on all your characters.

Comment: Hmm, I was just wondering for an easy way to get creds on my low level (10) chars. I don't have anyone at a high enough level (overall or slicing) to get creds on Yavin.

Comment: @ShadowZ. I suppose it's better than nothing, but it would be more effective to mail credits over from higher-level characters.